# Write file and usage nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express

For a school project I'm creating a portal for KVM using NodeJS and Express.

I need to adjust an XML file and then use that XML File to create an VM.

So i created 2 functions

CreateXML:

```
    function createXML(req, res, next) {
      var parses = new xml2js.Parser();

       fs.readFile('Debian7.xml', function(err, data){
          parser.parseString(data, function (err, result){
             result.domain.name = req.body.name;
             result.domain.memory[0]['$'].unit = "GB";
             result.domain.memory[0]['_'] = req.body.ram;
             result.domain.currentMemory[0]['$'].unit = "GB";
             result.domain.currentMemory[0]['_'] = req.body.ram;
             result.domain.vcpu = req.body.cpus;

             var builder = new xml2js.Builder({headless: true});
             var xml = builder.buildObject(result);

             fs.writeFile('./xmlfiles/' + req.body.name + '.xml', xml, function(err, data){
                if(err) console.log(err);
             });
          });
       });
    };
```

CreateDomain:

```
    function createDomain(req, res){
       var domainXML = fs.readFileSync('./xmlfiles/' + req.body.name + '.xml', 'utf8');

       hypervisor.connect(function(){
         hypervisor.createDomainAsync(domainXML).then(function (domain){
            console.log('Domain Created');

            res.json({success: true, msg: 'succesfully created domain'})
         });
       });
    }
```

then I call these functions as middleware in my post request

```
    apiRoutes.post('/domainCreate', createXML, createDomain);
```

But then when I use Postman on the api route I get the following error:

```
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './xmlfiles/rickyderouter23.xml'
```

After the error it still creates the XML file and when I create the XML file before I use postman it works fine. It's like it needs to execute both functions before the creation of the XML file, how do I create the XML file after the first function and then use it in the second function.

Comment: `fs.readFile` is async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it's asynchronous" (just like many, many problems in node.js/javascript).

- The `fs.readFile` function is asynchronous: when you call it, you give it a callback function which it will call *when it finishes loading the file*.
- The `parser.parseString` is asynchronous - it will call your callback function when it finishes parsing the XML.
- The `fs.writeFile` is the same - it will call your callback function when it finishes writing the file.
- The `hypervisor.connect` function is the same - it will call your callback function when it finishes connecting.

The middleware functions are called in order, but they both contain code that may not have completed before they return. So when your code calls `createDomain` and tries to read the XML file created in `createXML`, the XML file probably doesn't exist yet. The `fs.readFile` might not be finished yet; even if it is, the `parser.parseString` function might not be finished yet; even if *that one* is finished, the `fs.writeFile` might not be finished yet.

One way to solve this would be to put the functionality of the `createXML` and `createDomain` functions together into one middleware function. That would allow you to rewrite it so that all the function calls that depend on previous asynchronous function calls could actually wait for those calls to complete before executing. A simple way to do it would be this:

```
function createXML(req, res, next) {
  var parses = new xml2js.Parser();

   fs.readFile('Debian7.xml', function(err, data){
      parser.parseString(data, function (err, result){
         result.domain.name = req.body.name;
         result.domain.memory[0]['$'].unit = "GB";
         result.domain.memory[0]['_'] = req.body.ram;
         result.domain.currentMemory[0]['$'].unit = "GB";
         result.domain.currentMemory[0]['_'] = req.body.ram;
         result.domain.vcpu = req.body.cpus;

         var builder = new xml2js.Builder({headless: true});
         var xml = builder.buildObject(result);

         fs.writeFile('./xmlfiles/' + req.body.name + '.xml', xml, function(err, data){
            if(err) console.log(err);

            // notice the call to createDomain here - this ensure
            // that the connection to the hypervisor is not started
            // until the file is written
            createDomain(req, res);

         });
      });
   });
};
```

And change your route to:

```
apiRoutes.post('/domainCreate', createXML);
```

Now, that's pretty ugly. I don't like the idea of lumping those two middleware functions into one and I'd prefer to rewrite it to use a promise-based approach, but that's the basic the idea.

Comment: Thanks it works, I will take a look at promises and how they work.